# Java: List and Array fill each other in wrong way

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to make a program that makes a list of arrays with different entries.
There are two classes:
Class1 shall contain an array1 full of (seven) 0's;
In Class1 shall be a method that fills a list of seven Class2's;
Each of them shall contain an array that has six 0's and one 1 at different locations, like this:
Class2 number1: 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0. 
Class2 number2: 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.

and so on.

Then, I want to print all the entries. So that is what it should look like:

1
0
0
0
0
0
0 (end of Class2 number 1)
0
1
0
0
0
0
0 (end of Clas2 number 2)
And so on, until it prints the array of the one and only instance of Class1 that I used.
0
0
0
0
0
0
0

But instead, it just prints a long row of 1's.

My Code:

Class1:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Class1{

    int[] array1 = new int[7];

    public Class1(){

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            array1[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    public List<Class2> list(){

        List<Class2> returnlist = new ArrayList<Class2>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){

            returnlist.add(new Class2(array1, i, 1));

        }

        return returnlist;

   }

}
```

Second Class:

```
public class Class2{

    int[] array2 = new int[7];

    public Class2(int[] array, int index, int number){

        array2 = array;

        if (index >= 0 && index < array2.length){
            array2[index] = number;
        }

    }
}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main{

    public static void main (String[] args){

        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            System.out.println(class1.list().get(i).array2[j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        System.out.println(class1.array1[i]);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the objects of `Class2` you are assigning the array of Class1 to each object of Class2: `array2 = array;`

Arrays are not handed over by value, but instead by reference. Therefore each Class2 object is writing its `1` in the same array that is used by all the classes.
You will have to explicitely create a new array for each `Class2` object (which you do already) and then copy the values from the `array` parameter.

```
public Class2(int[] array, int index, int number){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array2[i] = array[i];
    }
    if (index >= 0 && index < array2.length){
        array2[index] = number;
    }
}
```